# How do I stop a printer from printing a cleaning page?

Tags: printing, printer, network-printer

So I got an HP M451dn to replace an old P4014, which our office used for printing a number of things. Whenever we go to print a check, we have to switch the cartridge from standard toner to a MICR cartridge, which is much more expensive so we tend to switch back and forth as needed. Both regular documents and checks appear to be printing just fine.

The problem is that with our new printer, every time we change the cartridge to our MICR toner and back again, the printer automatically brings up the "Press OK to clean" prompt, then prints out a cleaning page whether we press "OK" or not. Is there any way to disable this behavior? It does this whether it's connected to the network or plugged directly into the user's PC or even not hooked up to anything.

The HP support forums are no help. Is there anything we can do? I don't even care if we still have the default behavior, as long as we can stop the cleaning page from printing once it starts.

Comment: Lasers should not need a cleaning page when changing a cartridges, but, if HP want it that way I don't think there is anything you can do about it. Funny thing is, the manual does not even mention it. Does it also happen when you put an HP cartridge in?

Comment: @hdhondt Both are genuine HP cartridges, I believe. Happens with any cartridge switch, regardless of origin.

Comment: If it happens with any switch, then it's a "feature". But, I would expect the manual to at least mention it under "replacing cartridges" - it doesn't...

Comment: an HP printer finding an excuse to waste toner.  Who woulda thunk it?

Answer (score -1):

We have a ton of these printers at work and none do this that I've experienced.

The service manual indicates the cleaning page under service menu is not a factory default setting (asterisks (*) indicate the factory default setting)

So, go through the menu and find service > cleaning page and make sure there isn't a (*) next to it.

Comment: Nothing like that in the menus, at least not with an asterisk. The only option that mentions cleaning pages is the option to print one. On the bright side, I now have another two gratuitous cleaning pages for my collection! :-)